Using FastCGI cache with Nginx on Joomla site
I have a Joomla site running on an Ubuntu server using Nginx with PHP-FPM (no Apache, just Nginx and PHP). I’m trying to get the FastCGI cache working, but there is obviously a problem because it tries to cache pages like login pages and doesn’t seem to recognize when a user is logged in at all. The administrator pages are, correctly, not cached.
I have the following statements in my nginx.conf file, but they don’t seem to have any effect:
if ($request_uri ~* "/user/")
{
    set $no_cache 1;
}

#Don't cache if there is a cookie called PHPSESSID
if ($http_cookie = "PHPSESSID")
{
    set $no_cache 1;
}

if ($cookie_joomla_user_state = "logged_in")
{
    set $no_cache 1;
}

These statements are placed with the other “set $no_cache” statements, so I presume they are in the right place.
The login page is at domain.com/j5d/user/login-page, so I would have thought that the first condition would prevent caching that page, but it doesn’t — the page is still cached (as can be seen from the response headers).
I have checked that $cookie_joomla_user_state does have the value “logged_in” by setting a header which confirms this when the user is logged in. However, the above if-statement doesn’t cause the cache to be bypassed.
I would be grateful for any guidance on this question. Also, is there a way of checking whether these statements are actually executed? I’ve tried add_header inside the {…} of the if-statement, but this gives an error.
Update:
I have tried to do some debugging, replacing the if statements with map  statements. I now have the following:
map $request_uri $page_no_cache {
    ~*\/(user|administrator)\/    "npc";
    default                       0;
}

map $page_no_cache $no_cache {
    ~npc                1;
    default             0;
}

add_header X-Debug-b "Value of no_cache is $no_cache";

map $page_no_cache $debug_header_p {
    ~npc "Cache should be bypassed for page";
    default "";
}

add_header X-Debug-p $debug_header_p;

When I load the relevant page, I get the X-Debug-p header showing "Cache should be bypassed for page", meaning that the last map statement matched the ~npc regex. However, the X-Debug-b header shows the value of $no_cache as 0, meaning that the same regex did not find the same match in the same string - unless nginx has something else interfering with the assignment of a value to the $no_cache variable.
I am very new to nginx, so there may be something obvious that I am missing. I am thinking through this code as if it is executed line by line, as in most programming languages. Perhaps that is not the case?

Your first approach was in the correct direction. The problem was that you only declared a variable named "$no_cache" to a value of 1, but you did nothing with that value.
The following will perform what you want:
# Check if any of the conditions are met to bypass the cache
set $no_cache 0;

# Check for PHPSESSID cookie
if ($http_cookie ~* "PHPSESSID") {
    set $no_cache 1;
}

# Check if request URI is within the /user/ folder
if ($request_uri ~* "^/user/") {
     set $no_cache 1;
}

# Check if cookie_joomla_user_state contains the value "logged_in"
if ($http_cookie ~* "cookie_joomla_user_state=logged_in") {
    set $no_cache 1;
}

# Bypass cache if any condition is met
if ($no_cache) {
   set $skip_cache 1;
}

# Enable proxy caching, but respect the bypass flag
proxy_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
proxy_no_cache $skip_cache;


Thank you for that reply, Luis. In addition to your helpful comments, I found that I had my statements in the wrong server context. They were in a non-ssl context, but the pages I was testing were https pages. After getting that sorted out the caching is now working properly.
